# Hijacking node require even when spawning another script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to replace a specific package using

```
import Module from 'module';
const {require: oldRequire} = Module.prototype;
Module.prototype.require = function twilioRequire(file) {
    if (file === 'the-package-of-interest) {
        // return something else
    }

    return oldRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};

const p = require('the-package-of-interest');
// this gives me the replacement
```

This would work fine, but if this was placed inside a script that spawns another script, this does not work in the other script, i.e

```
// main.js
import Module from 'module';
import spawn from 'cross-spawn';

const {require: oldRequire} = Module.prototype;
Module.prototype.require = function twilioRequire(file) {
    if (file === 'the-package-of-interest) {
        // return something else
    }

    return oldRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};

spawn.sync('node', ['/path/to/another/script.js'], { stdio: "inherit" });

// another/script.js
require('the-package-of-interest');
// gives the original package, not the replacement
```

I don't suppose there is a way to spawn another script, but keep the hijacked `require` scope the same?

Comment: did my answer help? do you need any more help?

Comment: ? do you need any changes made to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Even though mocking libraries are usually used in tests, this might be a good situation to stub another library or file you wrote with another one based on a configuration.

There are a lot of mocking libraries for node, and there's a good article [which covers some of them](https://itnext.io/how-to-mock-dependency-in-a-node-js-and-why-2ad4386f6587).

The [library it recommends](https://github.com/theKashey/rewiremock) is pretty good but you can use whatever you want to do this

### Create a mock definitions file that replaces that import with the second file

First - define your mocks. You can do it in any place, this is just a setup.
Easiest way is to do this in the same file, but you can create a mock defitions file if you like

```js
 import rewiremock from 'rewiremock';
 ...

 // by mocking the module library, you actually replace it everywhere
 rewiremock('module')
    .with(otherModule);
```

your other module need to have the same export for this to work and act with the same interface.

### Replace the library based on a variable

To use, you need some sort of condition that will select if to use the original library or the second one

```js
// This is only needed if you put the mock definitions in another file
// Just put the rest of the code under the previous snippter
// if everything is in the same file
require('<your_rewiremock_definitions_file>');

if (replaceImport) {
  rewiremock.enable();
}

// run the code here

if (replaceImport) {
  rewiremock.disabled();
}
```

Your module should be replaced everywhere by the second module.

You can use any other mocking library to do this. there's a short section at the [start of the readme](https://github.com/theKashey/rewiremock#readme) with different options if you want a different style or another library.

`rewiremock` works by replacing the node.js cache so **it should change the dependency everywhere**.